# jQuery, not getting custom validate messages to work

Tags: jquery, arrays, validation, jquery-validate, message

I have the following field in a form:

```
<input id="edit-submitted-tel" name="submitted[tel]" value="telefoonnummer (optioneel)" size="4" maxlength="15" class="form-text" type="text">
```

I'm using jQuery Validate to check the form, it all works fine but I cannot seem to get my error messages to be custom per field. The below gives an error due to the field name and I have no clue what it should be:

```
$("#form").validate({           
    messages: {
        submitted[tel] : "tel error custom msg"
    }
});
```

What is this supposed to be when it is an array?

Comment: I believe your question has already been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816304/jquery-validation-validate-form-array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is simply a matter of [quoting](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29) your names properly.

From the documentation:

> If your form consists of fields using names that aren't legal JavaScript identifiers, you >have to quote those names when using the rules option:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    // no quoting necessary
    name: "required",
    // quoting necessary!
    "user[email]": "email",
    // dots need quoting, too!
    "user.address.street": "required"
  }
});
```

So in your case, it should just be a matter of this:

```
$("#form").validate({           
    messages: {
        "submitted[tel]" : "tel error custom msg"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Use two quotes

```
$("#form").validate({           
    messages: {
        "submitted[tel]" : "tel error custom msg"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi assim

```
var $params = {debug:false, messages:{}};

var $c_nome = $("#c_nome").attr("name");
$params['messages'][$c_nome] = "O campo de nome é obrigatório";

var $c_email = $("#c_email").attr("name");
$params['messages'][$c_email] = "Por favor insira um e-mail válido";

var $c_assunto = $("#c_assunto").attr("name");
$params['messages'][$c_assunto] = "O campo de assunto é obrigatório";

var $c_msg = $("#c_msg").attr("name");
$params['messages'][$c_msg] = "O campo de mensagem é obrigatório";

$("#form-contato").validate($params);
```