# Form validation with jQuery Validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

after a long research on internet i'm about to give up, let's say you are my last hope. My problem: I'm implementing a timesheet form for my company. This form is dynamic because in a day you can do several activities. The fields (included in a PHP page) are:

- Day (text field)
- Hours (drop down)
- Notes (a text field where the employee can write notes for the day)

All the fields listed are in a row enclosed in a fieldset. On the top of field set i've put a button, clicking it I will add another row with the data listed before. Now, before submitting to backend, I want, of course, put some validation rules which are the following:

- Field DAY must be required (it's my key in DB and i've added a DatePicker plugin)
- The sum of hours in an entire day can't exceed the 8 hours

I've tried to use Jquery Validate but seems I have two problems:

- It can't handle in somehow the arrays of data going to the script php that will write down on DB (for example the days submitted will arrive to backend in an array, I've decided this way because the number of days that can be recorded is not known before submission)
- It adds the controls only on first row

I've tried (as I've read in other posts) to add rules after the creation of new row, but, in that case, it works on other fields only if i put the cursor inside, I leave the field blank and then I click outside that field.

I attach my code, any help would be appreciated!!

greetings from Italy.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var i = 0;

    //fadeout selected item and remove
    $('.remove').live('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function(){ 
        $(this).empty();
        return false;
        });
    });


    $('a#add').click(function() {
        i++;
        var options = '<p>Day    <input type="text" id = "Day'+i+'" class = "Day" name="day[]">  </select>  hours<select id = "hours'+i+'" class = "hours" name="hours[]"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option></select>   Notes    <input type="text" id="Note'+i+'" class = "Note" name="note[]"><a href="#" class="remove"><img src="images\\remove.png" height="20" width="20"></img></a></p>';
        $(options).fadeIn("slow").appendTo('#extender');


    });

    $('.Day').live('click', function() {
    $(this).datepicker('destroy').datepicker({
        changeMonth: false,
        changeYear:  false,
        stepMonths:  false,
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        showOn:'focus'}).focus();
    });

});
</script>
```

this is where the dynamic fields are appended

```
<form name="rec_abs" method="post" action = "rec_on_db.php">

<fieldset>
<legend>Timesheet</legend>
<div id="extender"></div>
<p><a href="#" id="add"><img src="images\add.png" alt="" border=3 height=20 width=20></img></a>    </p>
</fieldset>

</form>
<input type="submit" value="Send your timesheet"></input><br>
```

Comment: If you've already "tried jQuery Validate" and failed, then show us that failed attempt.  Because your description of the problem makes no sense with respect to the plugin's default behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the fact that your elements are only validated when you change them, you can try using the plugin's [`onsubmit`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onsubmit) option:

```
$("form[name='rec_abs']").validate({
     onsubmit:true
});
```

When it comes to validating multiple fields, I'd suggest adding a class rule to your validation using the [`addClassRule`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/) method.

Define your rule the following way:

```
$.validator.addClassRules("my-day", {
  required: true
});
```

Then add the `my-day` class to your day elements.

Regarding the sum of the hours, look into the `addMethod` method. It enables you to define custom validation rules. Here's an example that checks if a phone number is in the `+XXXXXX` format (`X` is a number, `+` is optional):

```
$.validator.addMethod("phone", function(value, element) {
    // no phone number is a good phone number (the field is optional)
        if (value.length == 0) { return true; }
   // use a regexp to test the if the value is in the '+XXXXXX..' form
        return /^\+?(\d){5}\d+/i.test(value);
    }, 'Invalid phone number');
```

I've managed to get my validation to work on `ajax` loaded content before, while retaining my script in a separate file using class rules and custom methods.

Comment: [**As per documentation, *"A boolean `true` is not a valid value"* for the `onsubmit` option.**](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onsubmit)  That's because `true` is the default and by manually setting it `true`, you could potentially break the plugin.

Comment: Also, ***by default***, this plugin triggers validation on the `blur` and `keyup` events as well as the `submit` button's `click` event.  If the OP claims his elements were only validated with he changes them, then the OP's code is broken (he has not shown us).  Regardless, messing with the `onsubmit` option would have nothing to do with the `onfocusout` or `onkeyup` options.

Comment: I didn't read the docs well enough I guess, however I have been using a true boolean for the onsubmit for quite some time and have never had a problem.

Comment: Correction, you're _unaware_ of any problems users may have seen.  It's technically incorrect and I've indeed seen this cause various weird problems.  Just look at the plugin's source code and to verify for yourself.  Otherwise, if you think the developer's own documentation is wrong, please let him know on his GitHub page.

Comment: Meanwhile, what's the idea behind setting `onsubmit` to `true` when that's already the internal default?  If you're indeed modifying the plugin's behavior with `true`, then that's technically breaking the plugin.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't a problem, I said I never had one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply Sir Celsius. Now with the first modification you suggested I can validate my form at submit. There is more than this by the way. I modified the code generating the dynamic form as follows:

```
    $('a#add').click(function() {
        i++;
        var options = ' .... html of the row as before ...';

    $(options).fadeIn("slow").appendTo('#extender');


    $('#Day'+i).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        messages: {
        required: ""
        }  
    });

    $('#Hours'+i).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        messages: {
        required: ""
        }  
    });


    });
```

With these lines I add rules at newly created parts of document. I've put a counter just to make every cell have its own ID, class name remains the same. For my purpose I have to put data in arrays, every type of data has its own vector. Here is the problem. If all the fields have different IDs (OK for HTML), same CLASS (OK for HTML), BUT SAME NAME (ok for HTML but not for Jquery validation), the validation is operated only on the first row! To accomplish the aim I've made a modification to query.validate.js putting this code:

```
    checkForm: function() {
    this.prepareForm();
    for ( var i = 0, elements = (this.currentElements = this.elements()); elements[i]; i++ ) {
        if (this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length != undefined && this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length > 1) {
        for (var cnt = 0; cnt < this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length; cnt++) {
            this.check( this.findByName( elements[i].name )[cnt] );
        }
        } else {
        this.check( elements[i] );
        }
    }
    return this.valid();
    }
```

replacing the "standard" form

```
checkForm: function() {
this.prepareForm();
for ( var i = 0, elements = ( this.currentElements = this.elements() ); elements[ i ]; i++ )     {      
this.check( elements[ i ] );
 }
return this.valid();
}
```

as suggested at link [Jquery Validation validate form-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816304/jquery-validation-validate-form-array). Now the validation works perfectly. I will work at second part of validation (sum of hours) and I'll let you know! Thank you so much for the moment!

Comment: Glad I could help! Can you provide the code for the form rows you add? Is there no way to add a custom name for each field? The previous solution you mention is elegant, but it might not be very secure to change the plugin's code directly.

Comment: I know is not good to modify the source of library but as it is provided seems like it can't suite my purpose. Anyway the code that built the parametric row is the one contained in the first box, enclosed by:

    $('a#add').click(function() { var options = .....

For my purpose I wanted to send an array to php script, a clean array that passed validation. With this technique I can use an iterator and i will be able to get in position 0 of array day[] the day to record on DB, on position 0 of the other arrays I will have all other infos.

Comment: Show your `.validate()` method because **validation on submit is already the default behavior**.  By default, this plugin triggers validation on the `blur` and `keyup` events as well as the `submit` button's `click` event.  [Also, as per documentation, _"A boolean true is not a valid value"_ for the `onsubmit` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onsubmit).  In other words, something you have not shown us is breaking the plugin's default behaviors.